# Add Week Interval to Date Query

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL Query which delivers data well for current date, how can i set this query to query a week of data from curdate?

```
SELECT count( * ) as today_total_4 
FROM cdr 
WHERE dcontext='ext-queues' AND DATE(`calldate`) = DATE(CURDATE())
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a DATE_ADD function to get the date a week from now. (Either forward or back)

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

```
SELECT count( * ) as today_total_4 
 FROM cdr 
 WHERE dcontext='ext-queues' AND DATE(`calldate`) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Depending on your query requirements you can calculate 7 days back using:

```
DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
```

If you wanted your query to be everything since a week ago, then you'd change your query to have the following where clause:

WHERE dcontext='ext-queues' AND DATE(`calldate`) > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)

Comment: I think OP wants result of `DATE(\`calldate\`) > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)`

Comment: Thats possible.  I wasn't sure what date he was looking for (forward of back, equal, greater, less than, between etc.) I was hoping to give him an idea of the function can do to calculate date differences and he could go from there.  I will edit the post with some more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count( * ) as today_total_4 
FROM cdr 
WHERE dcontext='ext-queues' AND WHERE WEEK(`calldate`) = WEEK(DATE(CURDATE()))
```